# Angular 2 Slideshow with css animations

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations, angular

I am looking to have an array of image/video links in JavaScript and then create a slideshow with CSS animations.

Would it be best to only keep one/two images/videos actually in the page and swap them out with timeouts? I don't know how it will perform if I have 100+ images/videos loaded at the very beginning.

I am also looking for some angular 2 animation examples. The documentation for angular2/animate is a little lacking at the moment. Does anyone know of any code that I can look at to see how these APIs work?

Any other suggestions or links that you can think of would be greatly appreciated as well.

Comment: Angular2 animation isn't available yet